# What is proper driver board for 7" 40-pin TFT lcd for raspberry pi?

Tags: display

I bought this lcd https://www.adafruit.com/products/2354 last week, but I realize I can't do anything without driver board (or maybe it called controller board).

What is proper driver board for 40-pin TFT lcd for raspberry pi 3 B+ ?

**1.** 
https://www.adafruit.com/products/1928 This is lcd + driver board. I should have  bought this one. Maybe it working with my lcd, but if then another lcd left.

**2.**
http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-Quality-2AV-HDMI-VGA-Remote_60547466486.html?spm=a2700.7724838.0.0.wzG62r How about this? Is it working with the lcd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [the one recommended on the product page of your LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1590)? That way you minimize the probability of further incompatibilities..

Update: The difference between the driver boards recommended by Mark Smith and me are their interfaces. TFP401 must be connected to the Raspberry Pi via HDMI and (!) USB, RA8875 needs a GPIO connection using the SPI interface. Furthermore, RA8875 cannot be stascked upon the Pi directly as the GPIO ports' layout is  not the same.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google of "40 pin pixel dot clock to HDMI" turned up [this](https://www.modmypi.com/beagle-board/breakout-boards/tfp401-hdmidvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-breakout-with-touch) driver. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

- Couple of years late to the party, but https://www.adafruit.com/product/2453 is designed to connect this display directly onto the GPIO pins, and offers a cheaper way to use this display with specifically a Raspberry Pi.
- The slightly more expensive https://www.adafruit.com/product/2219 would provide an HDMI encoder if you prefer to access the GPIO pins for other purposes.

Both of these boards offer touch support via a micro USB port, and have slightly cheaper non-touch variants should you prefer that.